# Why all debug buttons disabled?

Tags: flashdevelop

I have installed flashdevelop in windows XP, and although I've installed java 6, all buttons of debugger are disabled ..

Any idea? please see attached image
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are disabled because the debugger isn't connected to any SWF.

Comment: Do you mean, I must compile first?

Comment: Yes the buttons will be enabled when you'll launch the compiled SWF from FlashDevelop.